# Exception when adding case type to custom field set

Tags: custom-fields, civicase

I have a custom field set that is used for cases of a certain case type. Adding a second case type brings up the following popup after saving:

> Warning: You have chosen to remove one or more subtypes. This will
> cause any custom data records associated with those subtypes to be
> removed as long as the contact does not have a contact subtype still
> selected.

Confirming it throws the exception:

> CRM_Core_Exception: Supplied Sub type is not valid for the specified
> entity in
> /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Custom/Form/Group.php on
> line 293

If I do the same on a custom field set for contacts it's fine, When creating a new custom field set for cases and adding the two case types I can save it but when trying to open it again this exception occurs:

> CRM_Core_Exception: Expected to find one CustomGroup record, but there
> were zero. in
> /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/Result.php
> on line 90

Seems to me that Civi thinks we are dealing with custom data for contacts here.

I am on CiviCRM version 5.70.0.

Comment: What is the Civi version?

Comment: The version ist 5.70.0.

Comment: I just upgraded to 5.71.1 and it's still there.